# Multiples of 3 and 5 with method and strict scheme

Tags: ruby, loops, if-statement, methods, return

```html
def sum_of_3_or_5_multiples(final_number)

    final_sum = 0 #cette variable est la somme finale qui sera retournée. Ici on l'initialise à zéro
    while final_sum < 1000   
        final_sum += 1  
    end
    current_number = final_sum
    
    if is_multiple_of_3_or_5?(current_number)
        puts current_number%3 == 0 || puts current_number%5 == 0 
      else
        # si la réponse est "false"…ben y a pas de else : ce "current_number" n'est pas multiple,
        # donc on passe au suivant en oubliant celui-là. On repart dans la boucle.
      end
  
    #Ici, positionne la fin de la boucle
  
    return final_sum #on retourne la variable qui contient la somme du tout
  end
  
  sum_of_3_or_5_multiples(11) #=> 33
  sum_of_3_or_5_multiples(10) #=> 23def sum_of_3_or_5_multiples(final_number)
```

I need to make a program that calculates the multiples of 3 and the multiples of 5 in a given pattern. So I did the loop that goes from 0 to 1000 with the right variables.

But I have a problem with the "if" loop. I don't see how I can put my formula when the "if" is already declared?

Hope this is clear enough.

I show you my code, the comments are those of the exercise.

Comment: Yes sorry, i have forget this, it's done, it will be easier to understand with

Comment: what errors are you getting? what results are you wanting? and what is your code in `is_multiple_of_3_or_5?`

Comment: That's exactly my question, in "if is_multiple_of_3_or_5? (Current_number)" I have to enter a command line, but I don't understand how we can do that? apart from adding another "if" just below? but that's not going to be a problem? Knowing that the "if is_multiple_of_3_or_5? (Current_number)" method begins with an "if"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your current code is broken in major ways ...

you could replace all of your code with:

```
def sum_of_3_or_5_multiples(final_number)
  puts true if is_multiple_of_3_or_5?(1000)

  return 1000
end
```

I'm making a lot of assumptions here, as it's hard to tell exactly what you're trying to do.

Assuming that you are looking for the sum of all values that are a multiple of 3 or 5, and that `final_number` is the maximum number of the highest possible multiple to sum, you will really be needing something more like the following:

```
def is_multiple_of_3_or_5? (number)
  return (number%3).zero? || (number%5).zero?
end

def sum_of_3_or_5_multiples(final_number)
  final_sum = 0
  1.upto(final_number) do |i|
    final_sum += i if is_multiple_of_3_or_5?(i)
  end
  final_sum
end
```

Comment: I just wanted to know if with my method "if is_multiple_of_3_or_5? (current_number)" which is imposed on me, if I could loop inside this one, knowing that this method starts with an "if"

Sorry for my English it is not very good.

Comment: then, assuming you can ignore the first `def` in my example code, that the above should work for you?

Comment: Thank you so much ! I especially wanted to understand and find the solution by myself, because I did not understand this way it is new for me but with the answer + my research finally understood. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minimal change to your code, which hopefully achieves what you wanted:

```
def sum_of_3_or_5_multiples(final_number)
  final_sum = 0
  current_number = 1

  while(current_number <= final_number) do
    if is_multiple_of_3_or_5?(current_number)
      final_sum += current_number
    end

    current_number += 1
   end
  
  return final_sum
end
```

Notes:

- There are many ways to implement this "loop", and keep incrementing the `current_number`. You could use a `for` loop, or `(1..final_number).each`, or use recursion, or use `1.upto(final_number)`, or use `final_number.times`, ... But however you do it, the critical thing that you needed to add to the `final_sum` **inside** the loop.
- I removed the part of your code saying `while final_sum < 1000`. I don't understand what this was trying to achieve. Why is there any condition of the `final_sum`, and what's the significant of 1000?!

Comment: the 1000 was for my exercise but I did my job badly and I presented myself badly I apologize. My question was mostly whether this was possible and how to put a loop or some other way inside "if is_multiple_of_3_or_5?" car I was confused! But thanks !